# GEO location inversed PHP and SQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently working on a campaign/advertisement script in Laravel 5.2. I'm having a table with ads, for example: Ad name, Location (lat/long), Radius (+10km).

Now I have a user location (lat/long). I want to see if he is in the radius of any ad and show the ad to him.

When I search on Google I only find solution to search ads based on lat/long + radius but I want to opposite. So see if a lat/long is in a radius of existing ads.

What is the best way to make this? And advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This should work, all you would need to do is add this function to your `User` model.

```
public function ads()
{
    return \App\Ad::
        crossJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', \DB::raw($this->attributes['id']))
        ->where(\DB::raw('69 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(users.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(ads.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(users.Longitude - ads.Longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(users.Latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(ads.Latitude))))'), '<=', 'ads.radius')
        ->get();
}
```

It's not a traditional Eloquent relationship so you won't be able to eager load it, although I'm sure that would be possible with more work.

In order to find a user's ads, you would simply do something like the following...

```
$ads = (new \App\User::find($user_id))->ads();
```

Note that this assumes both your `users` table and `ads` table contains a `longitude` and `latitude` column.  It also assumes your `ads` table has a `radius` column.  You might need to rename some columns but it should give you what you need.

Also this assumes your radius is in miles.  If you use km, instead of `69`, use `111.1111`.

Comment: See my reply below.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to the version of you user3158900.

Made a scope out of the function and the lat/long from the user is variable so I need them as a input in the query.

I now have this:

```
public function scopeAdsInLocation($query, $from_latitude, $from_longitude)
{
    $query = CampaignModel::
    where(\DB::raw('111.1111 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(' . $from_latitude . ')) * COS(RADIANS(campaigns.loc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(' . $from_longitude .' -
        campaigns.loc_long)) + SIN(RADIANS(' . $from_latitude . ')) * SIN(RADIANS(campaigns.loc_lat))))'), '<=', 'campaigns.loc_radius')
        ->get();
    return $query;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
$ads = CampaignModel::adsInLocation(51.191320, 5.987772);
var_dump($ads);
```

This code works, but only if I set the radius to a fixed value. So when I replace campaigns.loc_radius with '100' it works. But with the radius each campaign has it doesn't seem to do the job. Do you know maybe why? Or have a solution for this.

Comment: Is the radius an integer column?  Something might get a little screwy trying to compare strings like that.

Comment: It is a varchar column.